# Windows Phone 8.1 System.Security.Cryptography doesn't exist

Tags: cryptography, windows-phone-8.1

I need to use the System.Security.Cryptography namespace in my Windows Phone 8.1 app - specifically the rsa provider.
But there is no such namespace available when  i make a Windows Phone app. When I use Siverlight the namespace is there but I cant find it when creating standard Windows Runtime apps.
The MSDN documentation says that RSACryptoServiceProvider is available on Windows Phone 8.1, do I need to reference any additonal assemblies to get it working?

Comment: WinRT apps use a different crypto API, `Windows.Security.Cryptography`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows phone 8.1 this is different from windows phone 8. Use this instead:

```
Using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
```